# How To Dynamically Append Some Mark Content to a File Object

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file, collect some lines, batch process them and then post process the result.

Example:

```
with open('foo') as input:
    line_list = []
    for line in input:
        line_list.append(line)
        if len(line_list) == 10:
            result = batch_process(line_list)
            # something to do with result here
            line_list = []

    if len(line_list) > 0: # very probably the total lines is not mutiple of 10 e.g. 11
        result = batch_process(line_list)
        # something to do with result here
```

I do not want to duplicate the batch invoking and post processing so I want to know if could dynamically add some content to `input`, e.g.

```
with open('foo') as input:
    line_list = []
    # input.append("THE END")
    for line in input:
        if line !=  'THE END':
            line_list.append(line)
        if len(line_list) == 10 or line == 'THE END':
            result = batch_process(line_list)
            # something to do with result here
            line_list = []
```

So if in this case I cannot duplicate the code in `if` branch. Or if has any other better manner could know it's the last line?

Comment: You can't read and write to the same File handle without Controlling the File Pointer using `tell/seek`.

Comment: @stovfl I don't think zhuguowei wants to write the `THE END` mark to the file. I think the idea was to append this to the file *in memory*. But still I agree, this is not possible, unless you read the whole file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is not too large and fits comfortably in memory, you can read everything into a list, slice the list into sub-list of length 10 and loop over them.

```
k = 10
with open('foo') as input:
    lines = input.readlines()
    slices = [lines[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(lines), k)]
    for slice in slices:
        batch_process(slice)
```

If you want to append a mark to the input lines, you also have to read all lines first.